# react-native-hockey-app platform setup not complete

Tags: react-native, hockeyapp

I followed the steps mentioned in the guide "https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-hockeyapp".

Build for the app is also successful. But When I run my release.apk, It silently does nothing and install is not reflected on Hockey App dashboard.

So, I tried it in debug.apk, I am getting an error on red screen saying "**react-native-hockey-app platform setup not complete"** .

Can anybody help me with this issue ?

Comment: how are you building and running your app? Are you trying to run this on the emulator or on your phone.

Comment: No, I am running it on my device

Comment: Please provide more details so we could help further: 1）Have you created an APP on rink.hockeyapp.net? 2) Could you double check the App_ID in your JS file is identical to that on the HA dashboard: componentWillMount() {    HockeyApp.configure(HOCKEY_APP_ID, true);} 3)How did you install the app, downloaded from HA dashboard or via other ways?

Comment: 1) I have created the app on rink.hockeyapp.net   2) I checked the App_ID is correct   3) I downloaded the app from HA dashboard, transferred the apk in device and installed it.

Comment: I am getting the same error right now... did you manage to resolve the issue by any chance?

Comment: Have the very same issue. Works fine for Android. This seems to be an issue for iOS alone